# Set stroke width for Gesture.toBitmap()

Tags: android, gesture

It is possible to save a gesture as a bitmap with [`toBitmap()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/Gesture.html#toBitmap%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

But it seems the stroke width is always 1px.

How can I save the gesture as a bitmap with a larger stroke width?

Answer (score 1):

Looking, at the source code, it seems impossible to achieve.

I [rewrote the `toBitmap()`](https://gist.github.com/4375270) in order to answer to this question.